# Can't move file , because is used by another process

Tags: asp.net

I have many files in one directory, My app, must move some files to another directory. When I did this, first time works fine, but after that I have a exception like:
System.IO.IOException:  process cannot access the file because another process is using the file.

I close windows explorer, or any program, avoiding the use of the file, but the problem persists.

I move files in this way:

```
private void ExtractosRemover()
{
    string dirOrigen = '\\' + @"\" + servidor + @"\" + "EEQ_" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + @"\";
    string dirDestin = '\\' + @"\" + servidor + @"\" + "FacturasMatch_" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + @"\";
    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow grd_Row in this.gvwExtractosMatch.Rows)
        {
            File.Move(System.IO.Path.Combine(dirOrigen, clean(grd_Row.Cells[7].Text) + ".xml"), dirDestin);

        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {

    }
    catch (IOException ioex)
    {
        lbl_UbiDevMensaje.Text = string.Empty;
        lbl_UbiDevMensaje.Text = ioex.ToString();
    }


}
```

For the names of the files, I read a gridview, and I add the extensions.
I don't know what is happening,

Please, I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance.

best regards

Comment: What else are you doing with the file after you move it? Also, you can find what is locking it with ProcessExplorer.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your comment, proccess explorer or tasklist reveals nothing,
There are several files in the directory, my job is move them to another  directory (for knowing what files I must move, I use gridview values). The files previously are upload to the server by the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
Using server map

```
private void ExtractosRemover()
{
    string dirOrigen = "~/" + "EEQ_" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "/";
    string dirDestin = "~/" + "FacturasMatch_" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "/";

    foreach (GridViewRow grd_Row in this.gvwExtractosMatch.Rows)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Move( //Mover xml
            Server.MapPath(dirOrigen + clean(grd_Row.Cells[7].Text) + ".xml"),
            Server.MapPath(dirDestin + clean(grd_Row.Cells[7].Text) + ".xml")
            );

            File.Move( //Mover pdf
            Server.MapPath(dirOrigen + "RIDE_" + clean(grd_Row.Cells[7].Text) + ".pdf"),
            Server.MapPath(dirDestin + "RIDE_" + clean(grd_Row.Cells[7].Text) + ".pdf")
            );
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {  }


    }


}
```